# Developing plugin, where to place action hooks etc?

Tags: plugins, init

I am dividing my plugin code into multiple files and functions.

When I have a function and straight after it an action hook, or for example add_shortcode, should that line go straight after the function or in a plugin init function?

As an example, should I have something like this:

```
// Shortcodes.php file       
function myplugin_shortcode( $atts ) {    
    if ( !empty ($atts) ) {
        foreach ( $atts as $key => &$val ) {
            $val = html_entity_decode($val);
        }
    }
    myplugin_display_items( $atts );       
}

// Register shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'output-items', 'myplugin_shortcode');
```

OR a combination of the following two:

```
// Shortcodes.php file       
function myplugin_shortcode( $atts ) {    
    if ( !empty ($atts) ) {
        foreach ( $atts as $key => &$val ) {
            $val = html_entity_decode($val);
        }
    }
    myplugin_display_items( $atts );       
}
```

and

```
// Myplugin.php file
myplugin_init() {        
   // other initialisation code   
   add_shortcode( 'output-items', 'myplugin_shortcode');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like in your first example

```
// Shortcodes.php file       
function myplugin_shortcode( $atts ) {    
    if ( !empty ($atts) ) {
        foreach ( $atts as $key => &$val ) {
            $val = html_entity_decode($val);
        }
    }
    myplugin_display_items( $atts );       
}

// Register shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'output-items', 'myplugin_shortcode');
```

Comment: I agree. Unless you're wrapping your entire Plugin code inside a class or something, it's just fine to add callback/hook code pairs directly in the Plugin file, rather than inside another callback.

Comment: Wouldn't it be handier to have all hook actions and callbacks in one place rather than having to go through a few files to hunt them down?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Where you put the callbacks and add_shortcode calls is not really that relevant, as long as they're all included. Eg you can put them anywhere you like in your functions.php file, or in a plugin file, or in a file that's included by one of these files ... and the order is not relevant, unless I'm mistaken ... so you can still put them all in one place without putting the add_shortcode calls in an init